# insertFileFromBase64 method for PowerPoint or Excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint, office-js

Is there support for `insertFileFromBase64` method for PowerPoint or Excel using Office.js?

Is there any way around to insert an entire document in Office 365 for PowerPoint or Excel?

Thanks & Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't supported by Excel or PowerPoint.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.